# Rerun code block in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, yield, with-statement

I was looking to try to figure out a way to write something like this:

```
code_that_should_not_be_run_again()
with rerun_code_that_may_fail():
  another_method(x)
  run_me_again_if_i_fail(y)
code_that_should_only_be_run_if_above_succeeds()
```

Where the above would run that code, and catch an exception, if it was caught, then try to run the code, again. here would be a longer version of what I want:

```
code_that_should_not_be_run_again()
try:
  another_method(x)
  run_me_again_if_i_fail(y)
catch Exception:
  try:
    another_method(x)
    run_me_again_if_i_fail(y)
  catch Exception:
    raise Exception("Couldn't run")
 code_that_should_only_be_run_if_above_succeeds()
```

I was thinking I could probably use a generator, maybe catch that yielded content in to a lambda and then run it twice, somehow, but now sure how I can code something like this.

Is this possible in Python? Or maybe something similar to this that can be done?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def run_code():
    print 'will run'
    try:
      yield
    except SomeException:
      try:
        yield
      except SomeException:
        raise SomeException('couldn't run')
```

*Edit* Python wont' let you do what I want to do, so you can only use decorators on functions :(

Comment: Use the concept of recursion, if a method fails..

Comment: Recurse once and only once only if an exception has occurred? And also run the whole block of code? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Have a look at the `retry` decorator. Should do exactly what you need. Very useful for handling web resources which may fail sometimes, and you want to retry a set number of times before giving up. - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying

Comment: The question is; what test shows it failed? The code is easy.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retry/ This one is also an option, and has a cleaner way of retrying only on specific exceptions. You could also write your own retry decorator class as a nice exercise. ;)

Comment: guys, thanks for the help. I've expanded my example. Looking to be able to run a block of code, not just one method. Was thinking that the with syntax would be good for this when I write it.

Comment: Just a tip: it general is not a good idea to just catch a generic `Exception`. Try to find the specific exception that occurred.

Comment: correct, I have that, already in my initial design. This just pseudocode ;).

Comment: Why not use a loop?!

Comment: cause we want to put this in to a library and use it in several places in different projects. We are catching a specific exception, and we want to run that block of code, if it raises an exception, try to rerun, and if that raises again, then we will will probably log and bubble up that exception and kill the program.

Comment: So you're wanting to use a context manager specifically (`with` statement)? That's not the typical use for a context manager - you don't really have a resource you are trying to manage. You are just trying to rerun a block of code.

Comment: indeed... i'm thinking for this one, a contextmanager would be good. the syntax for how you would write this would look quite nice. I was trying to write one, but couldn't get it to work correctly. the reason for this is that we will want to do this, MANY times for many different pieces of code.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can add what you've currently done with the `with` context-exception handler to your question, and SO can help get that to work, if possible.

Comment: The issue with your current context-manager code is that when you use it with the `with` statement, you still only run the enclosed block once. I can't see a good way of getting the enclosed block to run again using a context manager, which really only has methods for __entry__ and __exit__. In a sense, the context manager is unaware of what code is in the enclosed block - it just yields to it, and picks up again when the block is finished. It's an interesting problem.

Comment: @AndrewGuy is right, but more importantly, the try/except doesn't do what you think in this context. It only catches Exceptions inside the block (just a yield in your case), not exceptions that happen while the generator has yielded.

Comment: very true.. thats why i put it on here :). I didn't get very far cause my python knowledge is limited. I'm more of a ruby guy, so a block would make sense, but python doesn't have blocks in that sense. They have context managers where they are used in try catch finally... The best I can think of is probably 2 context managers, that call one, then the other... not sure.

Comment: so basically you can't extract a try catch into some kind of retry with a yield? I saw that yields don't run in the same context, which is not nice :(

Comment: The yield here is really an aside, the "contextmanager" decorator is a silly way of turning a generator into a proper context manager. A context manager just has "enter" and "exit" code that gets run before and after the block. You can implement a context manager as a class with _enter_ and _exit_ methods. BTW i think I was wrong, I think context manager does some voodoo magic so you can in-fact catch error, but doesn't really help you in this case.

Comment: @BiRico so you think there's no way I can write something like the above? I'm starting to think it's not possible and that I'd have to decorate functions in order to do what I want.

Comment: https://mtomassoli.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/code-blocks-in-python/ looking at this now..

Comment: There may be some voodoo hackery that you could use to rerun code within the `with` statement, but it would require an additional functional block that then contains the code you want to rerun. It would also be a little less clear what exactly you are doing for anyone not 'in the know'. See this post here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255914/finding-functions-defined-in-a-with-block

Comment: In essence, getting a context manager to access the scope within the `with` block is tough. Probably don't try and do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the retry decorator - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retry/ - and under the scenario that you want to catch any `TypeError`, with a maximum of 3 tries, with a delay of 5 seconds:

```
from retry import retry

@retry(TypeError, tries=3, delay=5)
def code_block_that_may_fail():
    method_1()
    method_2()
    #Some more methods here...

code_block_that_may_fail()
```

Can't get too much cleaner than that.

Additionally, you can use the built-in logger to log failed attempts (see documentation).

Comment: Have a decorator like this, already... There's no way to wrap this in generator statement with a with syntax?

Comment: A generator is different from a context manager (`with`). Careful you don't confuse things here. You could possibly do it with a generator, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: sorry, confusing for me what to call it exactly. I'm reading up on the two, right now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone posts a better solution than this but I would use exactly that method, and perhaps with a decorator:

```
def retry_if_fails(fn, exception=Exception, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
    except exception:
        fn(*args, **kwargs)  # if this fails again here, the exception bubbles up
```

Of course, the issue is that you are only calling one function in `retry_if_fails` and not a two-stepper like what you've done.

You could create a list of functions and pass that in along with a separate list of lists for the arguments to each of the functions you want handled.

```
def retry_funcs(fns, all_args, all_kwargs, exception=Exception):
    # all_args is a list of lists
    # all_kwargs is a list of dicts
    try:
        for fn, args, kwargs in zip(fns, all_args, all_kwargs):
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
    except exception:
        for fn, args, kwargs in zip(fns, all_args, all_kwargs):
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

In this one, the list of lists for `args` and list of dicts for `kwargs` have to match up by order. An empty list or empty dict in either `all_args` or `all_kwargs` would enable you to not pass any args to a particular function, or only args, or only kwargs, or both.

```
fns = [some_func, another_func]
all_args = [['a', 'b'],  # args for some_func
            []           # no args for another_func
           ]
all_kwargs = [{'param': 'something'}, # kwargs for some_func
              {}                      # no kwargs
             ]
```

And instead of the list of `funcs`, `args` and `kwargs` being different, it might be easier to just put them in together like what the result of `zip`-ing would be, since that's how you'd know code in the calls anyway:

```
fns_with_args_and_kwargs = [(some_func, ['a', 'b'], {'param': 'something'}),
                            (another_func, [], {})
                           ]
# and then
for fn, args, kwargs in fns_with_args_and_kwargs:
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Already have a decorator like that... This would only work if I pass in the function call along with the args and kwargs. What I'd really like to do is pass in a block of code rather than just a function. Otherwise I'd have to keep declaring function for each block of code I'd like to rerun.

Comment: Am I missing something, aren't you just trading a `def` for a `with`?

Comment: @BiRico Yes, you're right. A `with` context manager as an exception handler would be more elegant.

Comment: Interesting... how would a list of functions work? Like what if that function has no args or kwargs? or args but no kwargs and vice versa?

Comment: Empty list for a function with no args. And I think an `all_kwargs` as a list of dictionaries to use.